# Authentication problem with mysql 8 using qt

Tags: mysql, qt, mysql-8.0

I am developing a qt (5.12.2) application which can connect to a mysql server. Recently i tried to connect to a mysql 8 server. I was unable to connect, and got the following error message:

```
Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: The specified module could not be found.
```

After some digging, i found out that the problem was because of the new encryption implemented in mysql 8.

One workaround to this problem was to set the server to the legacy authentication method.

Is there a solution without switching back to the legacy authentication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 possible problems which can cause this problem.

1. You are using the old way and connect with `QMYSQL` driver using the
   MySQL Connector/C (libmysqlclient.dll) connector which not supports
   MySQL 8 and the new authentication method.
2. The second way is that you are using the `QODBC` driver with an
   older release(<8.0) which not supports the new authentication
   method.

You can easily solve this problem by switching or upgrading to the latest `QODBC` driver. You can download the latest version from the MySQL [download page](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/). With this little example and with the right connector it will work.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db.setDatabaseName("Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};Server=example.com;Database=test;Uid=user;Port=3306;Pwd=password;WSID=.");
if (!db.open()) {
    qDebug() << db.lastError().text();
} else {
    qDebug("success");
}
```